# How can I route outbound traffic from an App Service integrated with a VNet containing a Service Endpoint to an external Azure hosted API?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, vnet

I'm trying to secure my containerized web app with a Premium V2 App Service Plan. I've enabled Service Endpoints for an integration subnet for the different App Services to restrict incoming traffic from each other except for the frontend (so all of them are integrated with the VNet and all have incoming traffic restricted to that VNet except for the frontend).

I have also other Azure services like Azure Functions or a Storage Account that can have inbound traffic restricted by using those Service Endpoints. However, One of the App Services calls an external 3rd party API that lies on Azure too. That API may or not be behind a static IP. However, it has a Custom Domain associated.

The problem arises when I try to connect to that API from one of the VNet integrated App Services. As the destination IP is inside one of the IP ranges that are added to the routing with the use of a Service Endpoint, traffic is sent via that Service Endpoint instead of simple Azure routing. I've tried overriding the route with a Route Table associated to that subnet but that seems not to be possible, with or without a NAT Gateway attached to the subnet. I guess Azure routing is prioritized here. I'm sure the route is not effective as I used it on a different subnet where I deployed a VM.

Is there any way I can use that Service Endpoint for my internal traffic only so it's not used when it goes to an Azure hosted API or I need to switch to a different approach like Private Endpoints or an ASE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We've been able to ask the 3rd party to disable blocking rules. It turns out they had a rule that blocked this specific traffic.
I already tried changing that setting, but didn't try putting a route table on it. However, it'd make no difference as I can't define a list of allowed outbound IPs belonging to Azure since we have no static IP to call.

Answer (score 0):

I am unsure what you're looking for but if you want to explicitly define routes you should try using app services setting "WEBSITE_VNET_ROUTE_ALL" = 1 which overrides the default precedence of routing and makes sure that every outbound call follows the route defined inside route table of subnet.
Use the following steps to add the WEBSITE_VNET_ROUTE_ALL setting in your app:
Go to the Configuration UI in your app portal. Select New application setting.

Enter WEBSITE_VNET_ROUTE_ALL in the Name box, and enter 1 in the Value box.

[image: Provide application setting]

When WEBSITE_VNET_ROUTE_ALL is set to 1, outbound traffic is still sent from the addresses that are listed in your app properties, unless you provide routes that direct the traffic elsewhere.

Comment: I've already tried enabling and disabling that, and it made no difference